# Even more Zen and CSS Sprites

Tags: css, sprite

I am very frustrated with trying to use [CSS Sprites](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp). I have asked a couple of times here, and got great advice, but still no solution. The problem is that I want my sprites in a horizontal line, not a vertical stack. I can't seem to find an example of this on the web, and all tutorials I have found seem to only describe menus and other vertical stacks.

I have given it my best shot trying to get the widths and display styles right but still to no avail.

The following code is my best shot. I'd appreciate it if anyone could look and tell me where I am going wrong. (Note the image referred to in the code is a 32x32 image with 4 different sprites in the obvious places.)

http://codepaste.net/4kwx2c

Comment: Is there a reason why you want them horizontally stacked and not vertically? Also, the same rules should apply...just using a different axis.

Comment: Am I being thick, or is there no way to see the code functioning as an html page on codepaste? It might be worth posting the relevant css sprite somewhere and using http://jsbin.com (or http://jsfiddle.net) to post a live demo.

Comment: Can you draw a picture that shows what you hope to accomplish? It is not particularly clear to me.

Comment: re @Tegeril's comment, vertically stacked sprites will usually result in marginally better compression for the image than horizontal, ie a slightly smaller file size. Not much but worth bearing in mind.

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
.LICtrlList
 {
    display: inline;
  }
```

change to

```
.LICtrlList
{
display: inline-block;
}
```